# memory leak from vector

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

I'm seeing I'm getting a memory leak from my vector I have, I've tried deleting the contents then clearing the vector, erasing the vector as well. My Crtdb is still informing me of memory leaks, I know it involves the vector because when i comment all vector related things i get no leaks.  Here is all my code is doing.

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <vector>
#include "MyClass.h"

int main(void){
    Obj *a = new Obj();
    std::vector<Obj> vec;
    vec.push_back(*a);

    Obj b = vec[0];

    vec.erase(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    delete a;
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At least show a minimal definition of `Obj`.

Comment: and `Obj` would be? A possible source of the leak is faulty memory management of `Obj`.

Comment: Your vector hasn't gone out of scope yet when you call the leak checker.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `Obj` that leaks, rather than `std::vector`, also ensure that `class Obj` does everything right about the [rule-of-three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: `std::vector::erase()` does not promise to return memory.  Destroying the vector does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your vector hasn't gone out of scope yet when you call the leak checker.

Comment: And @Drew Dormann said in a comment, std::vector::erase() does not promise to release memory.  You don't really want it to, either because if you reuse the vector which is normal behavior after an erase(), it would have to allocate more memory to replace what it had just deallocated.